# Xamarin Forms not work after upgrade Visual Studio 16.9.0

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

the fault is not mine but it is Microsoft that updates its products without respecting the people who work.
why don't they test before releasing an update?

after the visual studio update all my xamarin forms projects stopped compiling

```
Errore      Command too long
   in Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbClient.GetCommandBuffer(String command) in C:\A\1\36\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbClient.cs:riga 258
   in Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbClient.BeginWriteCommand(String command, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) in C:\A\1\36\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbClient.cs:riga 227
   in Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbClient.BeginWriteCommandWithStatus(String command, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) in C:\A\1\36\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbClient.cs:riga 274
   in System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1](Func`4 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   in Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbClientTaskExtensions.WriteCommandWithStatusAsync(AdbClient client, String command, TaskCreationOptions options) in C:\A\1\36\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbClientTaskExtensions.cs:riga 62
   in Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass62_0.<RunShellCommand>b__0(Task t) in C:\A\1\36\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:riga 403
   in System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()         0
```

I'm trying to debug on a physical device. I tried to delete the obj and bin folders but nothing has changed. are in trouble because of Microsoft

Comment: How do you propose Microsoft tests everyone's code before a release?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: it's not just my code that's not working. others are reporting the bug but no valid solution.

Comment: Have you try to create a new project to test? Does it throw the same error? If yes, you could try to report this issue.

Comment: I sent the report to Microsoft and they replied that it is being evaluated. a user wrote me that <<With version 16.9.0. I have a similar problem.
It is not possible to deploy with Xamarin on Android because it searches for this file:
“\obj\Debug \100\ android\assets\Xamarin.Auth.dll.mdb” without success.
Xamarin Forms version 5.0.0.2012 also has problems.
I am forced to use 16.8.0 and 5.0.0.1931.
 >>

Comment: For now, you could use the old version. And wait for feedback of the report.